# How to filter JSON data with good performances

Tags: java, json, performance, rest, filtering

I'm having a bit of a problem finding a good solution to this problem: i get JSON data from a RESTful API and i want to filter it according to specific values of a certain field,work with that filtered data and then send it to a client.

For example,take this JSON:

```
{
"element1": {
    "width": 500,
    "height": 500
},
"element2": { 
    "width": 300,
    "height": 200
},
"element3": {
    "width": 600,
    "height": 100
}

}
```

How can i filter out only the elements with,let's say, height>=200?Or width <=500?
Of course i can iterate over the whole data and get what i want,but it would take ages if the JSON is very big,and since i would like to serve as many clients as possible,this doesn't seem the right way to go..

PS: Just for your information, i'll be coding it in java..

Comment: There's nothing else you can do unless the API allows you to specify criteria.

Comment: I don't see any alternative to iteration. If you could get XML rather than JSON you could utilise XPath, which would probably be much quicker at this sort of thing.

Comment: JSon is not the most efficient format for this sort of thing.  You should filter the data before you convert it into JSon.

Comment: I doubt it would take ages on top of having already retrieved and parsed that data from the web service. Unless you can push the filtering into that remote API, you won't get much improvement.

Answer (score 0):

Try this example with ServletStream instead of FileIS

```
    import java.io.FileInputStream;

    import javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory;
    import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamConstants;
    import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamReader;

    import de.odysseus.staxon.json.JsonXMLInputFactory;

    public class Test {
        static XMLInputFactory ir = new JsonXMLInputFactory();

        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

            FileInputStream servletInput = new FileInputStream("d:/test.json");
            XMLStreamReader reader = ir.createXMLStreamReader(servletInput,
                    "UTF-8");
            int typ = reader.next();
            while (typ != XMLStreamConstants.END_DOCUMENT) {

                if (typ == XMLStreamConstants.START_ELEMENT) {
                    String tagName = reader.getName().getLocalPart();
                    if (tagName.equals("width")) {
                        if (Integer.parseInt(reader.getElementText()) > 500) {
                            System.out.println("!FOUND!");
                        }
                    }
                }
                typ = reader.next();
            }
        }
    }
```

Regards

Comment: Interesting API. How does it work? Can it really do streaming (i.e. avoid reading the whole JSON into memory in one chunk)?

Comment: Yes, try it yourself: create an d:/test.json with content:{
"element1": {
    "width": 600,
    "height": 500
},"element2": {
    "width": 600,
    "height": 500
},239-.,ßBROKENSTRUCTURE}}}}}};
You will see that the console write 2x !FOUND! and an stacktrace after that.